# Setting cell size when converting from GeoTIFF to ASCII

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, raster-conversion, ascii

I would like to convert a GeoTIFF file to a .asc file using the translate option. When I use the translate tool in QGIS it converts it, but my cell size is something like 0.0002 (the pixel size of the GeoTIFF). I have tried enforcing a cell size of 30m using the -tr command, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: "Can't seem to get it to work" is not helpful. What error messages or unexpected output do you get? What specific commands have you tried?